# Is there any way to be connected with the Dropbox SDK without having the captcha access screen each time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, captcha

I would like to be connected with the Dropbox SDK on iOS without allowing it every time. Is it possible?
[image]

I would just like the person log it with is Dropbox and password account, and that's all.

My main problem is that Dropbox is asking each time a captcha which is bugging me...
[image]
How can I avoid that captcha question?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you RTFM, you will have everything for your code. 
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/objective-c

Check the example provided by Dropbox:
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/tree/master/Examples/DBRoulette

It is probably because you ask several times the token...

Answer (score 1):

The [Dropbox iOS SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c) will automatically store the access token that results from the app authorization flow, so you only need to send the user through the flow once.

That is, check [if you already have an authorized user](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/blob/master/Examples/DBRoulette/iOS/CocoaPodsProject/DBRoulette/DBRoulette/ViewController.m#L58), and don't [call `authorizeFromController`](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#begin-the-authorization-flow) if so.

For reference, the captcha itself won't always be shown during login. Dropbox has an anti-abuse system that will decide if/when to show it on various factors, but that's not something you can turn on/off yourself.